# Wordpress shortcode with specific attributes cause server error

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have shortcode for listing social icons. I have commented out shortcode function to prevent any bug that could be caused by shortcode callback function. I have a lot shortcode options so we have shortcode below:

```
[socials profiles="facebook twitter linked in youtube vimeo stackoverflow pagelines weibo yelp bitcoin foursquare maxcdn stackexchange xing bitbucket trello github flickr google plus pinterest tumblr dribbble instagram dropbox skype renren" size="small" colored_bg="yes" active_bg="yes" jump="yes" jump_bg="yes" round=yes]
```

Shortcode function itself:

```
    <?php
add_shortcode('socials', 'shortcode_socials');

function shortcode_socials($atts, $content = null)
{

    $str = 'a';

    return $str;
}
```

This shortcode will cause continious webpage loading, and then webserver will be restarted.

From apache log:
[Mon Dec 08 02:35:48 2014] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225725 -- Restarting.

Are there any limitations for shortcodes attributes quantity or length?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried with less $atts? Also shouldn't "linked in" be "linkedin"?

Comment: Yes, i have tried, less atts works. Nope, doesn't matter what inside attrs if it's Text. They aren't processed anyhow in shortcode function as you see.

Comment: I found this at http://bit.ly/1zFdbqh - **"This problem often happens on Windows platform because of smaller Apache’s default stack size. And it usually happens when working with php code that allocates a lot of stacks.
To solve this issue, add the following at the end of apache config file, httpd.conf"**,

Comment: Thank You a lot for the info. Strange thing, that shortcode attributes not such long to create memory problems, very strange. It might be there are some bad things in WP attributes parsing algorithm.

Comment: I'd say the same thing. It's only a single char string (a) being returned so the rest should be irrelevant (outside of throwing the atts strings into $atts variables). One thing to bear in mind, no matter how much WordPress runs it's bug, admin improvements and security updates is a still just a blogging platform. Remember, right tool for the right job, if you're not building a blog, there is a better alternative than WordPress.

Comment: :) Drupal or Joomla ? - They are nightmare things. And WP is not only blogging platform, it's bad when people try to implement Jira on WP, or any CRM. But... It's very good for business websites, and big corporate websites as well. It has powerfull editor + editor plugins, i haven't seen such things in Drupal and Joomla (i haven't worked with joomla for an ages, but i remember what was before.) I very like the way WP work, it seems we just need to dig into shortcode atts parser and suggest solution for WP team. In any team could be stupid person ) or tired one. It might be he wrote crazy code.

Comment: I'm sorry but you're wrong. It's not good for business websites unless it's a home build job. If you are selling this to a business, unless they are a blog service you are selling the wrong platform. It's heavy and you're forced to build the website around the CMS limitations. Why would you stick with only the three (WordPress, Joomla, Drupal)? There's a whole world more out there. You can build far more freely using Laravel, Symfony, YII, Codeigniter or any of the zillions of frameworks or why not Vanilla PHP?

Comment: Sorry, but no - i'm not wrong. IF you understand what you are doing WP is perfect for such things. Use caching, even simple WP plugin WP supercache will solve most of your problems (except content that update frequently), there such thing as optimization, that should be done in any platform. I have enough experience to say (8+years WP and ~2years in drupal as well.Because it's too expensive to use framework, and write all the existed things again.No support as well, you create limitation for your customer.

It might be that you have another vision about what should be called Corporate website.

Comment: Agree to disagree then. I have over 10 yrs experience, worked with Wordpress and Joomla before and can say in my opinion, they are good only for cheap, low-end business websites only a short step up from Wix. A business website should be built around the needs of the client, not the capability of the CMS or limitation of the developer.

Comment: But usually client won't say all things he need, and you will get long term project if you choose manually developing everything with framework, that actually could be short term with using CMS. I have no such experience, so it might be you are right, but i can't believe for exampel that your team did something that is close to WP widgets/sidebars/rich editor. And it's hard and too expensive for client to update such things, usually new team will build their own system again.So, yep, it could be faster etc.But very limited solution i think. Everything you say make sense, that's just my vision.

Comment: Basic example - using TinyMCE on textarea field (to make inputting html block easy), insert it into the database and (example - in controller) **$this->data['widget'] = $this->db->get_where($whatever);** and in view **echo $widget;**